# Configure Antd with Express and Next.js

Tags: express, next.js, antd

Hope you all are doing great

I'm new to Next.js and struggling with the integration of Antd, Express custom server, and Next.js.
For the development environment, everything is working fine.  But when I run `npm run build` and `node server.js`, express won't load Antd. Running `next start` on production build works too, but then api won't work. It shows following error

[image: antd error with express.js]

My `.env` file is

```
HOSTNAME=localhost
PORT=3000
HOST=http://$HOSTNAME:$PORT
NODE_ENV=production
```

`Package.json` file is

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "exp": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "serve": "node server.js",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.17.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.5",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

My `server.js` file is

```
const next = require("next");

require('dotenv').config()

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

console.log(dev, process.env.NODE_ENV);

const app = next({ dev });

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const startExpress = require("./app");
app.prepare().then(() => {
  startExpress(handle);
});
```

My `app.js` responsible for Express code

```
const express = require("express");

const server = express();
server.get("/api/hello", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Request received");
  res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe 1" });
});

module.exports = function (handle) {
  server.all("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
};
```

And `next.config.js` is

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

`pages/index.js` is simple

```
import Head from "next/head";

import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { Button } from "antd";


export default function Home({ user }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Button type="primary" size="large">
        {user.name}
        {/* Button */}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
  const host = req.headers.referer || process.env.HOST;
  const res = await fetch(`${host}/api/hello`);
  const user = await res.json();
  console.log("User is:", user);
  return {
    props: {
      user,
    },
  };
}
```

I don't know if it is webpack configuration problem or next.config.js.

Comment: That's not really how you handle client and server side, you normally handle them in two different projects. Have `React`, `antd` and `next` in one, and start an API/http server with `express` in another. You seem to lack understanding of how web works in general, and StackOverflow is all about answering precise questions.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals Please take a look at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server, that's how they are configuring. This approach is used to prevent multiple code bases

Comment: Woah, TIL! Thanks! In this case I cannot help since you don't use the exact technos they recommend (http instead of Express), and I find the concept of running a front-end and a back-end in the same project at the same time extremely sketchy and confusing...

Comment: I used http instead of express, nothing worked. And you're right about architecture. This is a trade-off actually. I'm thinking of separating them too

Comment: Not related to the error, but you don't even need the custom server in this scenario. You can move the `/api/hello` logic directly into `getServerSideProps` as that runs on the server too.

Comment: I know the concept, but I think this approach makes serverless applications. The cold start is the drawback of serverless applications. Please let me know if you know of any solution to this